# Show last row of database MySQL VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How can I show the last row of data in database?

I have this code here but it only shows the first data row in database

```
Dim cnPodaci AsNew SqlConnection
cnPodaci.ConnectionString = "your connection string"
cnPodaci.Open()
Dim cm AsNew SqlCommand
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
cm.Connection = cnPodaci
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
dr = cm.ExecuteReader

If dr.HasRows Then

dr.Read()
txtBox1.text = dr.Item("ColumnName1")
txtBox2.text = dr.Item("ColumnName2")

dr.Close()

EndIf
cnPodaci.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add an "ORDER BY" to your sql. Like

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY XX desc"
```

Assuming XX is the name of the column which increases for every new row.

**Edit:**

consider:

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY XX desc limit 1"
```

It will return the last row, having chosen what XX is.

Comment: Here is another way of the many depending how he feels that day.           `    SELECT TOP 1 * 
 FROM TABLE ORDER BY xx DESC`